# return method refference to stream

Tags: java, java-stream, method-reference

I have a class `Care`

```
class Car{
  private int wheels;
  private int doors;
 
  ...   

  public int getWheels(){ return wheels;}
  public int getDoors(){ return doors:}
}
```

And I have a collection of the cars

```
List<Car> cars = ...
```

I want to calculate the average numbers of doors and windows in the collection. I could do this:

```
cars.stream().mapToInt(Car::getWheels).avg().orElse(0.0)
cars.stream().mapToInt(Car::getDoors).avg().orElse(0.0)
```

However, I want to create a dynamic function for this, for example:

```
public double calculateAvgOfProperty(List<Car> cars, String property){
  Function<Car,Integer> mapper = decideMapper(property);
  return cars.stream().maptoInt(mapper).avg().orElse(0.0);
}

public Function<Car,Integer> decideMapper(String ppr){
   if( ppr.equals("doors")  return Car::getDoors;
   if( ppr.equals("wheels") return Car::getWheels;
}
```

However, `.mapToInt()` requires `ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper` as argument, but the method reference is `Function<Car,Integer>`, and casting does not work.

However when I directly pass the method reference, for example `.mapToInt(Car::getDoors)`, it works.

How to cast correctly cast `Function<Car,Integer>` to required type then?

Comment: Just guessing: cant you just change the return type in the method signature to `? extends Car` (or something along those lines)?

Comment: Just a note: I'm not sure `.avg()` is available on the `IntStream` instance.

Answer (score 3):

You should not cast a `Function` to a `ToIntFunction` as they are not associated (`ToIntFunction` does not extend `Function`). They are however both functional interfaces, so the method reference can also be inferred directly as a `ToIntFunction`.

There is an [`average()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average()) defined in `IntStream`:

```
public double calculateAvgOfProperty(List<Car> cars, String property) {
    ToIntFunction<Car> mapper = decideMapper(property);
    return cars.stream().mapToInt(mapper).average().orElse(0.0);
}

public ToIntFunction<Car> decideMapper(String ppr){
     if( ppr.equals("doors"))  return Car::getDoors;
     if( ppr.equals("wheels")) return Car::getWheels;
     ...
}
```

Comment: of course, the `decideMapper` method needs to return something for the default case as well, or (perhaps better) throw an exception. (I realize you added the "..." for that reason, I just wanted to clarify what is omitted there)

Comment: The `decideMapper` is also problematic to begin with, in the sense that it does not extract the method in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to create a method like this:

```
private double calculateAvgOfProperty(List<Car> cars, Function<Car, Integer> function) {
    return cars.stream().mapToDouble(function::apply)
            .average()
            .orElse(0.0);
}
```

and then you can only call:

```
double r1 = calculateAvgOfProperty(cars, Car::getWheels);
double r2 = calculateAvgOfProperty(cars, Car::getDoors);
```

I don't understand very well your question, but you can replace `mapToDouble` with `mapToInt` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I'm sure, that you have quite a few compile time errors in your code:

1. Missing some closing braces in the `decideMapper` method;
2. You don't really return anything for the default case, from `decideMapper`;
3. calling some `.avg()` on IntStream, which is not available.